# Rails: flash message shows in the url as param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

Hi all my flash messages work in the normal fashion but there is an action in one of my controllers where the flash message does not work.

This is the view:

```
<%= form_tag update_status_order_path(update_status), method: :put do |f| %>
    <%= select(:order, :status, [['Active', 1], ['Inactive', 0]]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller action

```
def update_status
        if @order.update_order_status! params[:order][:status] 
            redirect_to show_orders_ofert_path @order.ofert, success: "Updated!."
        else
            redirect_to show_orders_ofert_path @order.ofert, error: "Error."
        end
    end
```

When I send the form the action is performed correctly, but the flash message is not displayed in the layout, instead is displayed in the url as a param, just after click the Update button it reloads and shows the url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/oferts/48/show_orders?success=Updated!
```

I have tried changing put to patch but it did not worked, even changing the action to work with respons_to block but it did not work, any idea?

this problem is only happening with that specific action because with the other actions I have the flash messages are isplayed normally.

Thanks

Comment: did you register those as flash keys? the default keys are `notice` and `alert`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The success and error keys are being used as parameters to the show_orders_ofert_path because there are no parenthesis.  Add parenthesis around the path helper arguments:

```
redirect_to show_orders_ofert_path(@order.ofert), success: "Updated!."
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! can you tell me what is the difference with pharentesis and without parenthesis? I used to pass arguments without parenthesis =/

Comment: The Ruby parser was incorrectly parsing all the arguments as arguments to the show_orders_ofert_path method.  It has no way to tell what you want unless you add some parenthesis to differentiate that the `sucess: 'Updated!.'` argument goes with `redirect_to` and not to `show_orders_ofert_path`. Make sense?